# Cannot Send XMLHttpRequest from Outlook OnMessageSend Smart Alert Add-In

Tags: xmlhttprequest, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook Add-In that includes an OnMessageSend Smart Alert event handler. Everything is working as I expect it to in the Outlook Web App, but any XMLHttpRequest I try to send from the on-send Outlook event handler will fail in the Desktop app. There are no cross-origin concerns, because I am sending the request to the same domain that the script is from (localhost:44300 in testing).

The on-send handler looks something like this:

```
function onMessageSendHandler(outlookE) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.sessionData.getAsync("stuffFromTaskPane", (e) => {
        var postObj = e.value;
         if (postObj) {
            Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync(sbj => {
                postObj.Subject = sbj.value;
                Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", bdy => {
                    postObj.Body = bdy.value;
                    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req.onload = () => {
                        //test code
                        outlookE.completed({ allowEvent: false, errorMessage: "request loaded" });
                    };
                    req.onerror = () => {
                        outlookE.completed({ allowEvent: false, errorMessage: JSON.stringify(req) });
                    };
                    req.onabort = () => {
                        outlookE.completed({ allowEvent: false, errorMessage: "Request to Server Was Aborted." });
                    };

                    //Real request commendted out 
                    //req.open("POST", "/someApiPath");
                    //req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    //req.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                    //req.send(JSON.stringify(postObj));
                    
                    //Test request just to try and get something
                    req.open("GET", "/SomeJsPath.js");
                    req.send();
                });
            });
         }
         else {
            outlookE.completed({ allowEvent: true });
         }
    });
}

// ------------------------------------- linkEvent ------------------------------------- \\
function linkEvent() {
    //When the webapp first calls this Office.context is not defined so we skip the first call in the webapp, but when this is called onReady everything is good to go
    if (Office.context && (Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC || Office.context.platform == null)) {
        Office.actions.associate("onMessageSendHandler", onMessageSendHandler);
    }
}

//The web-app needs to do the linkEvent at onReady. The desktop app just calls it.
if (Office.onReady) {
    Office.onReady(linkEvent);
}
linkEvent();
```

The error callback ends up getting invoked and gives me a req object that looks like this:

```
{
  "UNSENT": 0,
  "OPENED": 1,
  "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
  "LOADING": 3,
  "DONE": 4,
  "readyState": 4,
  "status": 0,
  "timeout": 0,
  "withCredentials": true,
  "upload": {},
  "_aborted": false,
  "_hasError": true,
  "_method": "GET",
  "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_/SomeJsPath.js",
  "_response": "Error code = 15 \n",
  "_ur1": "/SomeJsPath.js",
  "_timedOunfalseLtrackingName": "unknown",
  "_incrementalEvents": false,
  "_performanceLogger": {
    "timespans": {
      "network XMLHttpRequest_/SomeJsPath.js": {
        "startTime": 17021415053926
      }
    },
    "_extras": {},
    "_points": {
      "initializeCore_start": 1704415053788,
      "initializeCore_end": 1704415053795
    },
    "_pointExtras": {},
    "_closed": false
  },
  "_requestId": null,
  "_headers": {},
  "_responseType": "",
  "_sent": true,
  "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {},
  "_subscriptions": []
}
```

I'm guessing the "_hasError":true and "_response":"Error code = 15 \n" lines are trying to tell me something, but I'm not sure what. If I try to change the requested URL to request some arbitrary site with a GET request I get the CORS errors on the req object complaining about the origin (which I would expect). The add-in on-send event does activate fine in the Desktop app, it's only the HTTP request that is not working.

I've been following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough?tabs=xmlmanifest.

This is with the Desktop Outlook app. I have heard that some folks have been getting options to upgrade to the "new" look Outlook app, which I suppose is more like the web app, but not me yet.

Any ideas on how I might send an HTTP request from the on-send event?